# Prove that $\Bbb R$ satisfies Dedekind Theorem $\implies$ $\Bbb R$ satisfies Cantor's property of Nested intervals.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I was recently looking at the proof of the fact that " The assertion that the real number satisfies Dedekind's characterisation of  cuts is same as saying that it satisfies Cantor's Theorem on nested intervals.

To elaborate on this, I am trying to understand the validity of this:

$i.$ Let $A,B\in \Bbb R, A\cup B=\Bbb R,A\cap B=\phi,A\neq \phi,B\ne\phi$ and $a<b,\forall a\in A,b\in B.$ Then there exists  a unique element $c\in \Bbb R$ such that $a\le c\le b,\forall a\in A$ and $b\in B.$

$ii.$ $\Bbb R$ satisfies Cantor's Nested Interval Property.

> My version of "Cantor’s Nested Interval Theorem" is :
>
> Let $\{[a_n,b_n]\}$ be a sequence of closed and bounded intervals such that:
>
> $(i)$ $[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]\subset [a_n,b_n]$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ and
>
> $(ii)$ $\lim\delta_n=0$ where $\delta_n=b_n-a_n=\text{length of }\space [a_n,b_n].$
>
> Then $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[a_n,b_n]$ contains precisely one point.

And $i\implies ii$

So, precisely, I am trying to go through the proof  "$i\implies ii.$"

The proof demonstrated is:

Let us consider the set $A=\{x\in \Bbb R, x\lt a_n\space\text{for some}\space n\in\Bbb Z\}$ and $B=\Bbb R\setminus A.$

We  note that,

$i.$ $A\cup B=\Bbb R,$ and $A\cap B=\phi$

$ii.$ Clearly $A,B\neq \phi$

$iii.$ If $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ then $a\lt a_{n_0},$ for some $n_0\in \Bbb N$ and by definition of $B,$ $a_n\leq b$ for all $n\in \Bbb N,$
due to which $a\lt b.$

Thus by Dedekind's theorem, $\exists$ a unique $c\in\Bbb R$ such that $a\le c\le b,\forall a\in A$ and $\forall b\in B.$

As $a_n\in A$ and $b_n\in B$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$ we get
$$a_n\le c\le b_n,\forall n\in \Bbb N\implies c\in\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[a_n,b_n].$$ This proves $i\implies ii.$

---

Now, I will try to present my understanding of the proof systematically and I need some impetrations whether my understanding is correct or not. Here is my version of understanding the above proof:

> In the proof given, firstly, we considered a set $A.$ It is defined that $A$ contains all real numbers which is strictly smaller than a particular real number. Now, this particular real number is denoted by a symbol $s_n$ where $n$ is a natural number.
>
> Then we considered a set $B.$ Set $B$ is defined to contain all the real numbers that are not in the set $A.$
>
> Then, they asked us, to note $3$ things.
>
> The first point that was asked to note, (i.e $i.$ ) was that $A\cup B=\Bbb R$ and $A\cap B=\phi.$ This is indeed the case and is more than obvious by the way $A$ and $B$ is defined.
>
> In the second point $ii.$, again the fact that $A\neq \phi$ is something more than obvious as because, $\Bbb R$ is an infinite set. Same reasoning applies to $B$ as well, and so, $B\neq \phi$. But, then they wrote out   "Clearly, $A\neq \phi.$ Also $B\neq\phi$ for $b_n\in B$ for any $n\in\Bbb N.$"
>
> My concern is for the sentence, "Also $B\neq\phi$ ...". I understand that $B\neq \phi$.
>
> But the next part of the sentence, "for $b_n\in B$ for any $n\in\Bbb N.$" is confusing. (I don't understand the reason for writing this later part of the sentence.)
> I feel that there can be two reasons for writing this:
>
> *Reason 1:*  They wrote it as a reason for the more than obvious assertion,  "Also $B\neq\phi$", but this is unlikelely, for then, it makes no sense atleast in the way, it's written,
>
> *Reason 2:* They want to say, that they are denoting the elements of $B$ as $b_n.$
>
> I assume it's the *Reason 2,* but then it could've been written more better such as
> "Let us denote all the elements in $B$ as $b_n.$" If it were written clearly, just like this, it would've been more understandable.
>
> In the third point of the "required to note" things i.e $iii.$ it is mentioned that if we consider $a_n$ (in the definition of set $A$ i.e $A=\{x\in \Bbb R, x\lt a_n\space\text{for some}\space n\in\Bbb Z\}$ written at the beginning of the mentioned proof) as $a_{n_0},$ then all the elements of the set $A$ are strictly less than $a_{n_0}$( follows from the definition of the set $A$ ), and all the wlements of $B$ are greater than or equal to $a_{n_0},$ which directly implies, that all the elemnts of $B$ are strictly greater than all the elements of the $A.$ (ALso, there is small typo, in $iii.$ for, it's written
>
> *$iii.$ If $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ then $a\lt a_{n_0},$ for some $n_0\in \Bbb N$ and by definition of $B,$ $\color{red}{a_n}\leq b$ for all $n\in \Bbb N,$
> due to which $a\lt b,$*. But it should've been written "*$iii.$ If $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ then $a\lt a_{n_0},$ for some $n_0\in \Bbb N$ and by definition of $B,$ $\color{green}{a_{n_0}}\leq b$ for all $n\in \Bbb N,$
> due to which $a\lt b$*" ,for otherwise, it makes no sense).
>
> After these, they used Dedekind's theorem to conclude that $\exists$ a unique $ c$ such that $a\leq c\leq b,\forall a\in A,\forall b\in B.$
>
> Now, comes the last part, where thay say:
>
> "As $\color{red}{a_n\in A}$ and $\color{red}{b_n\in B}$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$ we get
> $$a_n\le c\le b_n,\forall n\in \Bbb N\implies c\in\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[a_n,b_n].$$ This proves $i\implies ii.$"
>
> I feel a *notational ambiguity is invited here.* This is because, in the definition of $A,$ they wrote that all the elements of $A$ should be less than $a_n.$ But in this portion, (if i am not mistaken,)  *they are using the same symbol, $a_n$ to denote the elements of $A .$
>
> I feel a change like this, (below) is necessary:
>
> "$A=\{x\in \Bbb R, x\lt \color{green}{a_n}\space\text{for some}\space n\in\Bbb N\}$", so that,
>
> "As $\color{red}{a_n\in A}$ and $\color{red}{b_n\in B}$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$ we get
> $$a_n\le c\le b_n,\forall n\in \Bbb N\implies c\in\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[a_n,b_n].$$ This proves $i\implies ii.$"
>
> makes sense. As then, we can indeed use $a_n$ to denote the elements of $A,$ without any confusion.
>
> (We now, note that $b_n$ in this portion, is used to denote the elements of $B$, so the inference we chose in *Reason 2* above, was justified.)
>
> Then, they concluded, that "...we get
> $$a_n\le c\le b_n,\forall n\in \Bbb N\implies c\in\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[a_n,b_n].$$ This proves $i\implies ii,$" which indeed follows from Dedekind's Theorem.
>
> So, yes, Cantor's Theorem on nested intervals (or, CNI) is  seen to be true.
>
> Thus, we have established CNI or rather  proved CNI by Dedekind's Theorem.
>
> Also, the  concern that,
>
> *"CNI holds for all  possible sequenes of real intervals of  the form $\{[a_n,b_n]\}$ and is it the thing proven/established here is simply, that CNI holds true in a particular Nested Interval Sequence?"*
> is  unnecessary and irrelevevant here. *That's because, from the definition of $A,$ if we replace $a_{n_0}$ ( remember,
> we modified the definition of $A$ minutely), by ( say,) $a_n'$, then CNI is proved for a different sequence of real intervals. As, $a_n$ is arbitary, so CNI can seen to be hold true for any sequence Nested Intervals.*

---

Is my understanding of the proof correct ?

Comment: My edit was for 2 typos. You had $B=\phi$ in Definition $i$. And an "s" for a "z" in "characterization".

Comment: @DanielWainfleet The second edit was not needed. Characterisation versus characterization is one of the many UK vs US spelling differences

Comment: By the way OP you can use `\emptyset` to denote $\emptyset$. I know $\phi$ is a notation for this too but ..

Comment: I haven’t read through all of it yet but your re-interpretation in the new edit is not correct. I’ll write up in more detail why that is later but I recommend you carefully compare what you wrote with what I wrote and what your text wrote. For now I only have space to say, it’s *Reason 1* **not** Reason 2. The symbol $b_n$ is already defined, and it is not true that every single element of $B$ equals $b_n$ for some $n$. Rather, they are explaining why $B$ is nonempty (you do that by showing it has at least one element, which is what they have done)

Comment: I've now given full comments for the updated interpretation

Comment: We have $a_1-1<a_1$ so $a_1-1\in A$ so $A\ne\emptyset$. Every $b_n\in B$ (and hence $B\ne\emptyset$)..... because if $b_n\in A$ then there exists $m$ such that $b_n<a_m$, but that would make $[a_n,b_n]\cap [a_m, b_m]=\emptyset.$

Comment: @FShrike . The program red-lines $s$ but accepts $z$. But I  don't really care.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure we're on the same page, I'm assuming (as is standard for the nested intervals theorem) that: $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is some given monotone nondecreasing sequence and $(b_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is some monotone nonincreasing sequence, with $a_n<b_n$ being true for every $n\in\Bbb N$ and furthermore it is true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(b_n-a_n)=0$.

---

Before proceeding, I believe it is technically more accurate to define $A$ to be: $$\{x\in\Bbb R:\exists n\in\Bbb N,\,x\le a_n\}$$Using a weak inequality. If we use a strict inequality, it might not be true that $a_n\in A$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

Both their $(iii)$ and your replacement $(iii)$ (concluding $a<b$) are trivial, to be honest. They just took a sentence or two to explain why this is the case: I challenge you to conclude $a<b$ without using an argument similar to theirs. Though, in more advanced texts something as simple as this would often be omitted by an author; how much detail authors include can really vary.

You say: "I feel that it is solely given as a reasoning for establishing $a<b$". That's right! But for a full proof, you'd like to establish everything for certain. Let me rephrase their reasoning: by definition of $A$, I know $a$ is less than or equal to *some* $a_n$, and by definition of $B$ I know $b$ is *not* less than or equal to *any* $a_m$ (i.e. it is *greater* than *all* $a_m$), and considering $n=m$ in particular we find $a<a_n<b$ will hold. Again, you can't deduce $a<b$ without saying something like this, and it is not so convoluted.

You say: "Isn't the fact $a<c<b$ [trivial]?" but this fact is not a fact! $c$ is defined to be such that $a\le c\le b$ but you can't get away with the strict inequalities $a<c<b$ (if you could, then that would contradict the Dedekind theorem. Why?)

For the second part:

For a real $x$, $x$ is an element of $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}[a_n,b_n]$ precisely (by definition of intersection) if $x$ is in every single $[a_n,b_n]$. That is, precisely if $a_n\le x\le b_n$ is true for all $n\in\Bbb N$. But hey, we know that every $b_n$ is in $B$ and every $a_n$ is in $A$, so we know $a_n\le c\le b_n$ is true for all $n\in\Bbb N$... so $c\in\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}[a_n,b_n]$. $c$ is in fact the only element of this set.

---

Comments on your updated interpretation:

> "It is defined that $A$ contains all real numbers which is [are] strictly smaller than a particular real number. Now, this particular real number is denoted by a symbol $s_n$ where $n$ is a natural number"

No, both sentences are not quite right. $A$ is defined to contain all real numbers strictly less than $a_n$ *for at least one $n$*, so there is no particular real number. Moreover it is not given the symbol $s_n$.

$A\neq\emptyset$ is not obvious "because $\Bbb R$ is an infinite set". For example, $\Bbb N$ is an infinite set and $A=\{x\in\Bbb N:x<a_n\text{ for some $n$ }\}$ where $a_n:=n$, then $A$ is actually empty. But $A\neq\emptyset$ *is* obvious, yes, because you can take any number $<a_1$ and such numbers exist. As I've already commented, it's actually "reason $1$" which you should consider. Reason 2 is not a reason, you're overloading the symbol $b_n$ - it is already defined - and it's also not true that every element of $B$ must equal $b_n$ for some $n$.

It is not true that all elements of $A$ are strictly less than $a_{n_0}$ for some *fixed* $a_{n_0}$. That's not what they're saying. Rather, for any element $x$ of $A$, there is *some* $n_0$ with $x<a_{n_0}$ by definition, but this $n_0$ *depends on $x$* (maybe).

Since "$a_{n_0}\le b$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$" doesn't mean anything, I have to disagree with you: their saying "$a_n\le b$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$" is just fine, and *in particular* you can set $n=n_0$ to conclude $a<a_{n_0}\le b$.

There is no notational ambiguity because **$n$ is not fixed**. This is a mistake you have made a few times. Your "changed definition" for $A$ is actually the same one you gave earlier. *It is not true that all elements of $A$ equal $a_n$ for some $n$*. You can't use "$a_n$" to denote the elements of $A$ and that's not what the authors are doing.

I'm not at all sure what you mean by the final paragraph that's in quotes. But since the sequences $(a_n),(b_n)$ are taken arbitrarily - up to the hypotheses for the theorem - and you've shown there's always a single point in the intersection, you conclude the CNI for all suitable sequences of nested intervals. This is a very, very common proof technique: "if [-] is true for arbitrary [-] then true [-] is true for all [-]". The reference you make to $a_{n_0}$ is not going to be correct ($n_0$ depended on $a$ and $a\in A$ was an arbitrary element, $a_{n_0}$ doesn't really have relevance to this meta-statement you're trying to make) and you didn't actually modify the definition of $A$.

Comment: My version of "Cantor’s Nested Interval Theorem" is : Let $\{[a_n,b_n]\}$ be a sequence of closed and bounded intervals such that $(i)$ $[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]\subset [a_n,b_n]$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ and $(ii)$ $\lim\delta_n=0$ where $\delta_n=b_n-a_n=\text{length of }\space [a_n,b_n].$ Then $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[a_n,b_n]$ contains precisely one point. But I think your version is a bit altered, isn't it?

Comment: @ThomasFinley No, we are talking about the same thing. The monotone sequence condition and the $[a_{n+1},b_{n+1}]\subseteq[a_n,b_n]$ condition work out to be the same.

Comment: It's starting to make some sense. I have understood that my replacement for $(iii)$ is the same as the previous $(iii)$  which was written initially just some extra rigorization added. However, I don't still understand the "For the second part..." in your post. To phrase better, I am confused. Where did $b_n$ come from ? Also, a sequence being non-increasing doesn't necessarily mean, it has to be decreasing. In order to show that Cantor’s nested Interval Property holds valid, one must show that for every possible real and closed interval $[a_n,b_n]$ . But I dont see where it's shown?

Comment: @ThomasFinley Where did $b_n$ come from? I'm not sure what you mean by that, since you asked about $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}[a_n,b_n]$ which features $b_n$...  I show that $c\in\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}[a_n,b_n]$, which is what you asked about. I'd be happy to elaborate on the proof if you have a specific question about what I wrote, but at the moment I'm not sure what the problem is. ("one must show that for every possible real and closed interval $[a_n,b_n]$" - show *what*?)

Comment: I admit, it sounds confusing. I edited my post and tried to be as clear as possible. Please take a look at it. Thank you!

Comment: @ThomasFinley Has the question changed? I'm not sure. Is there something in my post that still needs explaining, or would you only like a verification that what you've said in the new edit is correct?

Comment: "would you only like a verification that what you've said in the new edit is correct?" Yes, exactly! That's what I want to know.

Answer (score 0):

More simply, first, we have $c\not\in A$. Otherwise:

If $c<a_n$ for some $n$,  then $(c+a_n)/2<a_n$, so $(c+a_n)/2\not\in B$ by def'n of $B$, so $c<(c+a_n)/2\in A$, contrary to $\forall a\in A\,(a\le c).$

So we have $c\in B$.

Now $c\le b_n$ for every $n$. Otherwise:

[1].  If $b_n<c$ for some $n$ then we cannot have $(b_n+c)/2\in B$ because then $c> (b_n+c)/2\in B,$ contrary to $\forall b\in B\,(c\le b).$

[2]. So by [1], if $b_n<c$ for some $n$ then $(b_n+c)/2\in A.$  That implies $(b_n+c)/2<a_m$ for some $m,$ so we would get $a_n\le b_n<(b_n+c)/2<a_m\le b_m,$ implying $a_n\le b_n<a_m\le b_m,$ implying the intervals $[a_n,b_n], [a_m,b_m]$ are disjoint, contrary to "nested".

So we  have $\forall n \,(c\le b_n), $ and because $c\in B$ we also have $\forall n\,(a_n\le c)$.

Comment: In chess we say "To  win you must use all your pieces". In math(s) you usually must use all your hypotheses. The nestedness of the intervals must be used somewhere. BTW my A is a proof of a more general result: If $F=\{[a_n,b_n]: n\in J\}$ is a non-empty family of non-empty bounded closed real intervals (where $J$ is some arbitrary index-set) such that no 2 members of $F$ are disjoint, then $\cap F\ne\phi.$

Comment: I will be glad if you comment on my now edited post.